# Google apps password reterival

Tags: google-workspace, account-recovery

I have lost my admin as well as secondary email (use as to retrieval of admin pwd) password. Please suggest steps which really works.
I know its possible but that person who knows is not ready to tell how.
Its Urgent.
There is some Google link for it PLZZ tell how step by step
Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

This may be what your are looking for:

[Reset Google Apps Administrator Password](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561?hl=en)